# How to get content-type from the response headers with Fetch

Tags: javascript, get, fetch-api, response-headers

I'm trying to access the returned `content-type` from my `GET` request so I can decide the kind of preview I want to like for `html` maybe pass through an iframe and for a PDF maybe some viewer. The problem is when I do `console.log(response.headers)` the object returned doesn't have content-type in it but when I check the networks tab the response headers has content-type:html/text. How can I get the content-type from the response headers?
this is how my GET request looks like

```
const getFile = async () => {
    var requestOptions = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: context.client_header,
      redirect: "follow",
    };
    let statusID = context.currentStatus.ApplicationID;
    var response = await fetch(
      process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT +
        "/services/getStatus?ApplicationID=" +
        statusID,
      requestOptions
    );

    console.log(response.headers);

    if (response.ok) {
      let fileHtml = await response.text();
      setfileURL(fileHtml);
    } else {
      alert.show("Someting went wrong");
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers) object isn't a great candidate for `console.log()` since it is not easily serialisable.

If you want to see everything in it, try breaking it down to its entries via spread syntax

```js
console.log(...response.headers)
```

You'll probably find that you can in fact access what you want via

```js
response.headers.get("content-type")
```

See [`Headers.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/get)

Comment: `response.headers.get("content-type")` worked! Thanks!